# How to post form value to url and database using php

Tags: php, forms, url, post

Please I need help on how to post a form data to a url which also goes to a database. this is the code I developed but it seems not to be working and it is not sending the information to the database and to the curl

```
include_once('Libraries/libraries.php');

//send the info to this page via POST method.

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$state = $_POST['price_2'];
$v_merchant_id = $_POST['v_merchant_id'];
$merchant_ref = $_POST['merchant_ref'];
$memo = $_POST['memo'];
$item_1 = $_POST['item_1'];
$price_1 = $_POST['price_1'];
$item_2 = $_POST['item_2'];
$price_2 = $_POST['price_2'];
$notify_url =$_POST['notify_url'];
$success_url = $_POST['success_url'];
$fail_url = $_POST['fail_url'];
$total= $_POST['price_2'] + $_POST['price_1'];

if ($price_2 == 'Lagos'){
    $item_2='COST OF DELIVERY WITHIN LAGOS';
    $price_2='';}
elseif ($price_2 !='lagos'){
    $item_2='COST OF DELIVERY OUTSIDE LAGOS';
    $price_2='5000';};
//connect to database a run sql "INSERT INTO" query.

if (isset($_POST['name'])){
$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name,phone,email,address,price_2,v_merchant_id,merchant_ref,memo,item_1,price_1,total) 
VALUES (:name,:phone,:email,:address,:price_2,:v_merchant_id,:merchant_ref,:memo,:item_1,:price_1,:total)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':price_2', $price_2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':v_merchant_id', $v_merchant_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':merchant_ref', $merchant_ref, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':memo', $memo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':item_1', $item_1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':price_1', $price_1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':total', $total, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
};


$loc = 'location:https://voguepay.com/pay/?v_merchant_id='.$v_merchant_id.'&merchant_ref='.$merchant_ref.'&memo='.$memo.'&item_1='.$item_1.'&price_1='.$price_1.'&item_2='.$item_2.'&price_2='.$price_2.'&notify_url='.$notify_url.'&success_url='.$success_url.'&fail_url='.$fail_url.'';
header($loc);
//that last line redirects the user to the api site submitting the username.
```

Here is my CURL

```
//preparing the posted value as argument and value for the sms gateway
$postValue = "v_merchant_id=".$v_merchant_id."&merchant_ref=".$merchant_ref."&memo=".$memo."&item_1=".$item_1."&price_1=".$price_1."&item_2=".$item_2."&price_2=".$price_2."&notify_url=".$notify_url."&success_url=".$success_url."&fail_url=".$fail_url.""; 
//the sms gateway address provided by your gateway

$apiUrl = "https://voguepay.com/pay/";
//next is to fake a browser form submitted 
//firefox is our choosing browser
$browserType ="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";

//initiating the curl library
$ci = curl_init(); 

//set the url to be used  for processing the data
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL,$apiUrl); 
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

//set our browser type that has been initiad before
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $browserType);

//set the maxmium time to execute the script before timing out
curl_setopt($ci,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2); 

//accept the response after the execution 
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

// set the post method for passing variables to the server 
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//assigning the values to be posted to the sms gateway
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postValue);

//execute the function and get result from the gateway
$a=curl_exec ($ci);

curl_close ($ci); // close the connection
```

Comment: "WHAT" is not working? Please provide errors output, etc.

Comment: So you need to POST data to this page? Did you try anything? (like curl?)

Comment: I've googled the same title you set and it returned a long list with a lot of examples: https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=How+to+post+form+value+to+url+and+database+using+php&oq=How+to+post+form+value+to+url+and+database+using+php&gs_l=hp.3...692.692.0.1541.1.1.0.0.0.0.196.196.0j1.1.0...0.0.0..1c.1.17.hp.CM9XR75PiwU

Comment: What are the errors you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, break your code up into sections and test each section.

First, test that you have received the data correctly. A single error can stop the entire page from processing, so ensure you are receiving what you think you are receiving:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
...etc...
$zz = 'RECEIVED DATA:<br /><br />';
$zz .= 'Name: [' .$name. ']';
$zz .= 'Phone: [' .$phone. ']';
$zz .= 'Email: [' .$email. ']';
echo $zz;
die();
```

Next, make sure that your MySQL insertion is working. Strip the code down to only 3 or 4 essential fields, run a test, and check the database. Did any data go in? Then, build it up and make sure an entire record enters correctly.

Finally, once you are sure that the previous two are working perfectly, then add in the code for your prayment processor.

Comment: thanks for the tip.resolved the database issue. trying to use curl to resolve the posting of data.